# Why are conductive chassis double insulated appliances allowed in the UK?

Tags: grounding, mains, insulation, earth, regulations

MacBooks are infamous for 'buzzing' to the touch while charging. If another (properly Earthed) laptop touches one, it can flicker the screen or shut down. If I plug one of these same properly Earthed laptops in to charge while it's already connected to my not-Earthed double insulated (also buzzy) Marantz amplifier by HDMI, the video cuts out and has to be replugged.

This is crazy, and only an issue with imported goods it seems. Anything of UK / Europe origin is either three pin or *actually* double insulated, usually plastic bodied. Why is this allowed, when it's demonstrably failing, and why is it (presumably) not a problem in the US or Japan where these problematic goods originate and Earthed appliances (even sockets for them) aren't so common?

I suppose they still get the 'buzz', but the lower likelihood of coming into contact with another device that *is* Earthed mitigates the various other glitches that plague those devices here?

Comment: Laptops aren't connected directly to mains voltage, so mains voltage regulations about insulation do not apply to them, just their chargers.

Comment: @user1850479 True, but Apple's charger isn't Earthed (except the longer one that's discontinued/sold separately), that's the issue. I assume the others must connect the shield to Earth. The amplifier *is* connected directly to mains, just not Earthed.

Comment: The Apple charger doesn't need to be earthed as long as it is double insulated, which they typically are since they're made of white plastic.  The laptop, which is powered by 20V over USB, doesn't need to be double insulated or grounded for the same reason a USB thumb drive doesn't need that, no mains connection.

Comment: All my Mac laptops came with the mains cable to connect to the charger block - standard in box.

Comment: Japan and the US use much lower AC voltages than EU/UK. This fact has a knock on effect when considering the Y capacitor used in non-earthed wall-warts to reduce high frequency switching noise on their output. And, although the switching noise is low so is the AC passed through the Y capacitor in US/Japan installations.

Comment: @SolarMike They used to include both a long 3-pin (not dummy Earth) cable and the stub plug with a dummy Earth pin (in the UK), these days just the latter. (It's actually a conductive pin, but NC.) If you search 'macbook touch buzz' or similar you'll find it's a common complaint. What's worse to me is when such equipment comes into contact with others that does use mains Earth and shuts down or cuts out a data connection, flickers the screen etc. I'm not really expecting a 'fix' to be suggested here, I'm just baffled that it's allowed and half-expecting someone to say it isn't.

Comment: To be clear I'm not suggesting it's *dangerous* (and perhaps that's why it, if it is, is allowed?) I just think it's mental, and so easily avoidable.